# Get Pricebookentry.StandardPrice value into soql query

Tags: trigger, soql

I am writing soql query to get unitprice,standard price fields which are in pricebook entry object.

```
[SELECT
    Id, Unitprice, UseStandardPrice, StandardPrice
    FROM PriceBookEntry
]
```

But if i use without "Pricebookentry.StandardPrice" in soql query it is working fine. How to get Pricebookentry.StandardPrice values into query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2.isStandard = true and Id = 'yourId'
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts it is working fine. I am able to get details. I marked it as best answer just now.

Comment: please also upvote  my answer (+1). Happy for you!

Comment: Sure can u pls help me in another question i posted most recent 1, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64891/can-i-update-standard-amount-in-opportunity-from-custom-object                                     here is link

Comment: I already posted click on above link and comment there is possibility or not

Comment: ok let me read!